# ¿Cómo guardar imagen en un servidor con c#?

Tags: c#, fileupload

Quiero guardar una imagen en una dirección de servidor, por ende, el `image.SaveAs(path)` no me sirve, ya que esto solo es para una dirección física.

Ya lo he intentando con `FileUpload`, pero me dice que la imagen no se encuentra en la dirección.

Anexo mi código:

```
var archivo = Request.Files[fileKey];

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName);
//string nombre = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(archivo.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(archivo.FileName).Replace(".", "");
//string path = System.IO.Path.Combine("https://abc.com/imagen", "imagen"+ "." + extension);
myWebClient.UploadFile("https://abc.com/imagen/",nombreArchivo);
//archivo.SaveAs(path);
```

Actualizacion, encontré el resultado:
var archivo = Request.Files[fileKey];
                        string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName);
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(archivo.FileName).Replace(".", "");

```
                    string rutaArchivoTemp = $"{ParametroArchivos.RutaFotografia}{residenteId}.{extension}";

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(rutaArchivoTemp))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(rutaArchivoTemp);
                    }

                    byte[] datosArchivo = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(archivo.InputStream))
                    {
                        datosArchivo = binaryReader.ReadBytes(archivo.ContentLength);
                    }

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(rutaArchivoTemp, datosArchivo);
```

Comment: quizas esto no responde a tu pregunta, pero has pensado en guadarla en la base de datos y no en en un directorio?

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas como funciona el `UploadFile()` del `webClient` veras que este requiere algo del lado del servidor que trabaje con el file que le estas enviando.

[WebClient.UploadFile Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_UploadFile_System_String_System_String_)

Si revisamos la documentacion veras que lo primero que menciona es el parametro de la url, no es cualquier url la que definas

> The URI of the resource to receive the file. For example, ftp://localhost/samplefile.txt.

en este caso menciona que es un `ftp`, pero se puede realizar con una web si del otro lado se procesa la imagen

cuando utiliza

```
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```

esa `uriString` es una pagina del lado del servidor que implementa

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("c:\\inetpub\\test\\UploadedFiles\\" + file.FileName);
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

en este caso es un `aspx` que debes invocar pasandole el archivo y esa pagina hace el `SaveAs` en el servidor

Peor hay algo del lado servidor a procesa lo que se esta subiendo, ya sea un `ftp` o un `aspx`